# Javascript : how to make multiple div slide from left

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i'm trying to create onclick div slide from left or right currently i had written a script for onclick slide but problem it that when i'm trying to insert one more button and div to do same than first one is working fine but when i click on second one there are no result. here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to WE</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .sidenav {
            height: 100%;
            width: 0;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #e8fbfc;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: 0.5s;
            padding-top: 60px;
        }

        .sidenav a {
            padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #818181;
            display: block;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .sidenav a:hover {
            color: black;
        }

        .sidenav .closebtn {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 25px;
            font-size: 36px;
            margin-left: 50px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
          .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
          .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNews()">&times;</a>
        <div class="row" style="height: 600px;border: 2px solid #636e72;background:#dfe6e9; margin-left: -30px;">
            <?php if ($uid!=$sid) { ?>
                <marquee direction = "up" height="100%" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
                <?php
                    $uid=$_SESSION['id'];
                    $post=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id`='$sid' AND `type`='Follower' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
                    while ($r_post=mysqli_fetch_assoc($post)) {
                        $userid=$r_post['user_id'];
                        $follower=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `id`='$userid'");
                        $u_row=mysqli_fetch_array($follower);
                        $followerlst=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `follower` WHERE `sender`='$uid'");
                        while ($f_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($followerlst)) {
                            if ($r_post['user_id']==$f_row['reciver']) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="postsingle1">
                                    <a href="activity-post.php?id=<?php echo $r_post['post_id']; ?>">   
                                        <div>
                                            <?php 
                                                $extn=substr($r_post['image'],-3);
                                                if ($extn=="mp4") {
                                                    echo "<video  width='100%' height='160px' controls><source src='uploads/".$r_post['image']."' type='video/mp4' ></video>";
                                                }
                                                else { 
                                                    echo "<img src='uploads/".$r_post['image']."' width='100%' height='160px'  />";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{ ?>
                    <marquee direction = "up" height="100%" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
                <?php
                    $uid=$_SESSION['id'];
                    $post=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id`='$sid' AND `type`='Profession' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
                    while ($r_post=mysqli_fetch_assoc($post)) {
                        $userid=$r_post['user_id'];
                        $follower=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `id`='$userid'");
                        $u_row=mysqli_fetch_array($follower);
                        $followerlst=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `follower` WHERE `sender`='$uid'");
                        while ($f_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($followerlst)) {
                            if ($r_post['user_id']==$f_row['reciver']) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="postsingle1">
                                    <a href="activity-post.php?id=<?php echo $r_post['post_id']; ?>">   
                                        <div>
                                            <?php 
                                                $extn=substr($r_post['image'],-3);
                                                if ($extn=="mp4") {
                                                    echo "<video  width='100%' height='160px' controls><source src='uploads/".$r_post['image']."' type='video/mp4' ></video>";
                                                }
                                                else { 
                                                    echo "<img src='uploads/".$r_post['image']."' width='100%' height='160px'  />";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </marquee>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mySearch" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeSearch()">&times;</a>
        <div class="row" style="height: 600px;border: 2px solid #636e72;background:#dfe6e9; margin-left: -30px;">
            <?php if ($uid!=$sid) { ?>
                <marquee direction = "up" height="100%" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
                <?php
                    $uid=$_SESSION['id'];
                    $post=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id`='$sid' AND `type`='Follower' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
                    while ($r_post=mysqli_fetch_assoc($post)) {
                        $userid=$r_post['user_id'];
                        $follower=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `id`='$userid'");
                        $u_row=mysqli_fetch_array($follower);
                        $followerlst=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `follower` WHERE `sender`='$uid'");
                        while ($f_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($followerlst)) {
                            if ($r_post['user_id']==$f_row['reciver']) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="postsingle1">
                                    <a href="activity-post.php?id=<?php echo $r_post['post_id']; ?>">   
                                        <div>
                                            <?php 
                                                $extn=substr($r_post['image'],-3);
                                                if ($extn=="mp4") {
                                                    echo "<video  width='100%' height='160px' controls><source src='uploads/".$r_post['image']."' type='video/mp4' ></video>";
                                                }
                                                else { 
                                                    echo "<img src='uploads/".$r_post['image']."' width='100%' height='160px'  />";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else{ ?>
                    <marquee direction = "up" height="100%" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
                <?php
                    $uid=$_SESSION['id'];
                    $post=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id`='$sid' AND `type`='Profession' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
                    while ($r_post=mysqli_fetch_assoc($post)) {
                        $userid=$r_post['user_id'];
                        $follower=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE `id`='$userid'");
                        $u_row=mysqli_fetch_array($follower);
                        $followerlst=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `follower` WHERE `sender`='$uid'");
                        while ($f_row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($followerlst)) {
                            if ($r_post['user_id']==$f_row['reciver']) {
                                ?>
                                <div class="postsingle1">
                                    <a href="activity-post.php?id=<?php echo $r_post['post_id']; ?>">   
                                        <div>
                                            <?php 
                                                $extn=substr($r_post['image'],-3);
                                                if ($extn=="mp4") {
                                                    echo "<video  width='100%' height='160px' controls><source src='uploads/".$r_post['image']."' type='video/mp4' ></video>";
                                                }
                                                else { 
                                                    echo "<img src='uploads/".$r_post['image']."' width='100%' height='160px'  />";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </div>

                                <?php
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </marquee>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function openNews() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "350px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
        }

        function closeNews() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
        }
        function openSerach() {
            document.getElementById("mySearch").style.width = "350px";
            document.getElementById("mySearch").style.marginLeft = "250px";
        }

        function closeSearch() {
            document.getElementById("mySearch").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("mySearch").style.marginLeft= "0";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

.  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .                                     .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: lol marquee has the event listeners and if the browser doesn't support marquee, it is most likely the event listeners won't work.